# want to separate and add matching values from two columns in pandas

Tags: python, dataframe

```
this is how my data looks like
source_x target_X weight_X source_y target_y weight_y
harry     hermoine   5      harry     ron       2
hagrid     harry    9        ron      hermoine  3
ron       hermoine  8       hagrid     ron      8
voldemort  snape    3        snape     harry    5
harry      ron      6        hermoine  harry    9
```

what i want to do is have two columns of source and target with weight. if source_x==source==y, target_x==target_y then i want their weights to be summed. if it doesnt match the source andtarget are there with  their values

here's what i have tried:

```
df['matches'] =  (df['target_X'] == df['target_y']) & (df['source_x'] == df['source_y'])
df['summed'] = df['weight_X'] + df['weight_y']

which gave this output
    source_x    target_X    weight_X    source_y    target_y    weight_y    matches summed
1   harry      hermoine      5          harry       hermoine        2       True    7
2   hagrid     harry         9          ron          hermoine      3       False    12
3   ron       hermoine       8          hagrid       ron            8       False   16
4   voldemort   snape       3           snape        harry          5       False   8
5   harry       ron         6          hermoine      harry         9       False    15
```

so basically what i want is one source and target and weight, if it has matching values it sums the value. i was thinking i could do this by if else or make two different datasets, and then append. but i am not really sure how to go about it.

```
  this is what i want in the final output:
     source    target   value
     harry    hermoine   14 
     hagrid    harry     9
     ron       hermoine  11
     voldemort  snape    3
     harry      ron      8
     hagrid      ron     8
     snape       harry   5
     hermoine    harry   9
```

what it basically is , source and target is who said to whom, weight is how many times, so i want a list of all who talks to whom ,how many times(hope this helps understanding a bit)

Comment: Can you please give the expected dataframe, i.e, the correct solution to your query?

Comment: Yes i did, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you want to combine the columns 'source' and 'target' and sum the columns 'weight' when the values of the other two columns match in the exact order. In short I would split the dataframe, rename the columns, [concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) and then use the [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function to group according to the source and target columns and sum over the weights:

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                                                                                         

In [2]: data = {'s_x': ['harry', 'hagrid', 'ron', 'voldemort', 'harry'],  
   ...:         't_x': ['hermoine', 'harry', 'hermoine', 'snape', 'ron'], 
   ...:        'score_x': [5, 9 ,8, 3, 6], 
   ...:        's_y': ['harry', 'ron', 'hagrid', 'snape', 'hermoine'], 
   ...:        't_y': ['ron', 'hermoine', 'ron', 'harry', 'harry'], 
   ...:        'score_y': [2, 3, 8, 5, 9]} 
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data) 
   ...:  
   ...: df                                                                                                                                          
Out[2]: 
         s_x       t_x  score_x       s_y       t_y  score_y
0      harry  hermoine        5     harry       ron        2
1     hagrid     harry        9       ron  hermoine        3
2        ron  hermoine        8    hagrid       ron        8
3  voldemort     snape        3     snape     harry        5
4      harry       ron        6  hermoine     harry        9

In [3]: df1 = df.loc[:,['s_x', 't_x','score_x']].rename(columns={'s_x':'s', 't_x':'t', 'score_x':'score'}) 
   ...: df2 = df.loc[:,['s_y', 't_y', 'score_y']].rename(columns={'s_y':'s', 't_y':'t', 'score_y':'score'}) 
   ...:  
   ...: df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(by=['s','t']) 
   ...: df4 = df3.sum().reset_index()
   ...: df4                                                                                                                                         
Out[3]: 
           s         t  score
0     hagrid     harry      9
1     hagrid       ron      8
2      harry  hermoine      5
3      harry       ron      8
4   hermoine     harry      9
5        ron  hermoine     11
6      snape     harry      5
7  voldemort     snape      3
```

You have to use [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) after grouping to transform the multi-index into two normal columns, but the required info is already present in the grouped dataframe.

Comment: could you please explain whats happening here.